# Google Apps Script: Loop through a list

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a deleteEachRow function that loops through a sheet and delete Rows that have a particular Column Value.

This works fine and was hoping to modify it in such a way that it loops through a multile sheets in the work-book and also delete rows based on multiple Column Values.

The deleteRow() script

```
//GLOBALS
 
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetID"); 
var SHEET = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
 
 
var DELETE_VAL = "abc";
var COL_TO_SEARCH = 4; // The column to search for the DELETE_VAL (Zero is first)
 
  
function deleteEachRow(){
  
  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  
  //Reverse the 'for' loop.
  for(var i = rangeVals.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH] === DELETE_VAL){
      
      SHEET.deleteRow(i+1); 
    };
  };
};
```

What I have tried..

```
var SHEET = SS.getSheetByName(["Sheet1", "Sheet2"]);
 
var DELETE_VAL = ["abc","DEF"];

function deleteEachRow(){
  
  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  
  //Reverse the 'for' loop.
  for(var i = rangeVals.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    for(var i=0; size = DELETE_VAL.length; i < size; i++){
        if(rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH] === DELETE_VAL[i]){
         for(var i=0; size = SHEET.length; i < size; i++){
             SHEET[i].deleteRow(i+1); 
      };
     };
    };
  };
};
```

Which completes executing from my logs, but does not actually work. I may have murdered some logic here, please pardon me, I am new to .gs/.js.

Thanks for your anticipated response.

Answer (score 3):

Issue : You're passing array to `getSheetByName`, whereas as per documentation it accepts String only. i.e. Name of the single sheet you want to fetch.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename

So you can modify your function to take sheet name as input and then delete rows in that sheet. Then call your function with desired sheet names. Something like this:

```
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetID");  
 
var DELETE_VAL = "abc";
var COL_TO_SEARCH = 4; // The column to search for the DELETE_VAL (Zero is first)
 
function deleteEachRow(sheetName){
  var SHEET = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  
  // existing logic
};

// Invoke deleteEachRow() for each sheet you want to delete the rows
["Sheet1", "Sheet2"].forEach((sheetName) => deleteEachRow(sheetName));
```

Comment: Hi @Umair Mohammed

This worked quite well, Although it threw an error.

Please is there a way modify this to pass a list of items to *DELETE_VAL*?

Comment: Yes. you can make DELETE_VAL to be an array and loop through it using forEach (etc). 
Optimised version would be to use map/dictionary instead of array - that way you won't need to loop through the array.
Please try it out and if you're stuck feel free to open new question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @Umair Mohammed, thanks for this really.

What you suggested did work, and this has really optimised the task, however I have tried as you said to implement a for-loop through an array for deleting the multiple items.

I have not succeeded, I have post the challenge [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68065518/challenge-looping-through-an-array-to-delete-rows-in-google-apps-script), hope you could check it out.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Umair is right, there was a simply error in the first line. But I'd want to add that the `sheet.deleteRow(row)` is not the best practice in case if there are many rows to delete. This command is quite time consuming.

If you have more than dozen rows to delete it's better to grab all data from a sheet (or range) `var data = range.getValues()`, clear the sheet (or the range), to process the array inside the script and refill the sheet back with new data `new_range.setValues(array)`. It will work much faster.

Comment: Thanks @Yuri Khristich, my knowledge here is quite limited and really wished this could understood thoroughly. However I have posted a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68065518/challenge-looping-through-an-array-to-delete-rows-in-google-apps-script), could you help, check it out.

I can not thank you enough.