# Challenge Looping through an array to delete rows in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following function deletes rows in a Google sheet based on a specific value/item, I was hoping to modify this to take an array of items to delete.

*Original function*

```
//GLOBALS
 
 
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET ID"); 
 
 
var DELETE_VAL = ["Item_to_delete 1", "Item_to_delete 2", "Item_to_delete 3"]
var COL_TO_SEARCH = 5; // The column to search for the DELETE_VAL (Zero is first)
 
  
function deleteEachRow(sheetName){
  var SHEET = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  
  //Reverse the 'for' loop.
  for(var i = rangeVals.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH] === DELETE_VAL){
      
      SHEET.deleteRow(i+1); 
    };
  };
};

// Invoke deleteEachRow() for each sheet you want to delete the rows
["SHEET 1", "SHEET 2", "SHEET N"].forEach((sheetName) => deleteEachRow(sheetName))
```

I have tried passing a for-loop that goes through each item but it throws an error:

```
//GLOBALS
 
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET ID"); 
 
 
var DELETE_VAL = ["Item_to_delete 1", "Item_to_delete 2", "Item_to_delete 3"]
var COL_TO_SEARCH = 7; // The column to search for the DELETE_VAL (Zero is first)
 
  
function deleteEachRow(sheetName){
  var SHEET = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  
  //Reverse the 'for' loop.
  for(var i = rangeVals.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    for(var i = DELETE_VAL.length; i >=0; i++){
        if(rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH] === DELETE_VAL[i]){
      
           SHEET.deleteRow(i+1); 
      };
    };
  };
};

// Invoke deleteEachRow() for each sheet you want to delete the rows
["SHEET 1", "SHEET 2", "SHEET N"].forEach((sheetName) => deleteEachRow(sheetName));
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property '7' of undefined

Meaning it is no longer reading the rangeVals variable.

I have also tried

```
.
.
.
// Invoke deleteEachRow() for each sheet you want to delete the rows
for(var i = DELETE_VAL.length; i >=0; i++){
   ["SHEET 1", "SHEET 2", "SHEET N"].forEach((sheetName) => deleteEachRow(sheetName));
};
```

But this just executes indefinitely until Time out.

I know i've definitely flawed some logic, but i'm almost there, please help.
My knowledge of .js/.gs  is minimal.

What I have tried again.

```
    function deleteEachRow(sheetName){
  var SHEET = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  
  //Reverse the 'for' loop.
  for(var i = rangeVals.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    for(var j = DELETE_VAL.length; j >=0; j--){
        if(rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH] === DELETE_VAL[j]){
      
           SHEET.deleteRow(j+1); 
      };
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: Appreciate your efforts to make it work! Don't worry as far you don't give up - we can make it word. One thing to note, you're running loop from DELETE_VAL.length to 0, and incrementing value of i. I guess you want to decrement it, right? Let's start with this. Do post exact error if you get any.

Comment: You are declaring the same var i in your outer and inner loops. Use a different letter for the inner loop index, like j.

Comment: I have updated my function to look like this, but the behaviour is weird - deletes rows  than were specified.

Comment: Please see my last edit, the code looks horrible as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issues:

- If you have two nested `for` loops, make sure both counter variables are not the same (`i`).
- `j` is used as an index of `DELETE_VAL`. This doesn't correspond to the sheets rows you want to delete (`SHEET.deleteRow(j+1);`). That should be `i` instead (`SHEET.deleteRow(i+1);`).
- Also, instead of having an inner `for` loop, I'd suggest using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in order to check whether the array `DELETE_VAL` includes the corresponding cell value. This way, there's no need to declare `j`, which has been the cause of this confusion.

#### Code snippet:

```
function deleteEachRow(sheetName){
  var SHEET = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  for(var i = rangeVals.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if (DELETE_VAL.includes(rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH])) {
      SHEET.deleteRow(i+1);
    };
  };
};
```